# Question about Svelte's reactive statements with typescript

Tags: typescript, svelte

I got the `TS2695` error in this code.

```html
<script lang="ts">
  let count = 0;
  
  $: count, (() => {
    console.log(`TEST: ${count}`);
  })();
</script>
```

The error was the below.

> Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects. ts(2695)

I thought the left side of the comma operator is the `count` variable, and it is used by console.log().

So, I didn't know how to handle this error. However, the code works well.

Please help me how to fix this error.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not used by `console.log`. A reactive statement in Svelte is a piece of code that executes everytime anything inside it changes. Svelte take care of finding the dependencies at compile time for you.

The proper syntax for what you're trying to do is

```js
$: console.log(`TEST: ${count}`);
```

or

```js
$: {
  console.log(`TEST: ${count}`);
}
```

On both, console.log is invoked with `count` passed to it, so Svelte is able to infer it as a dependency, you don't need to specify it.

Comment: What I want to test is using a reactive statement with a function call. I learned it can do with comma-separated.

Comment: It's actually a hack to make Svelte catch a variable as a dependency.

If you have a function `doSomething` and you write

`$: doSomething()`, Svelte won't know any variable `doSomething` uses. Then, by doing

`$: myVar, doSomething()`, you're tricking the compiler into making `myVar` as a dependency even though it's not being used anywhere, which makes TS right and unhappy. So, the only way to deal with this error is by ignoring it...

Comment: But in this case (self-invoking function), you don't need to use this trick at all, since Svelte will detect the dependencies correctly (it relies on static analysis of the block scope next to the `$:`);

Comment: wow, clearly understood. Thank you for the explanation!!